# Laravel - Eloquent query not returning relation via 'with'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I have the following query that should return relations but is not.

The models involved are Person and Role.

The Person relation:

```
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'person_role', 'user_id', 'role_id')
            ->where('person_role.org_id', $this->defaultOrgID);
    }
```

The roles relation:

```
    public function people()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class, 'person_role','role_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

Troublesome Query:

```
    $persons = Person::with('roles')
        //->selectRaw('person.personID, person.lastName, person.firstName, person.login, op.OrgStat1, person.defaultOrgID')
        ->select('person.personID', 'person.lastName', 'person.firstName', 'person.login', 'op.OrgStat1', 'person.defaultOrgID')
        ->leftJoin('person-email as pe', 'pe.personID', '=', 'person.personID')
        ->leftJoin('org-person as op', 'op.personID', '=',
            DB::raw('person.personID and op.orgID = ' . $this->currentPerson->defaultOrgID))
        ->leftJoin('role_user as ru', 'ru.user_id', '=',
            DB::raw('person.personID AND ru.orgID = ' . $this->currentPerson->defaultOrgID .
            ' AND EXISTS (select roles.name from roles where roles.id = ru.role_id and roles.name ="%' . $query . '%")'))
        ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->orWhere('person.firstName', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                ->orWhere('person.lastName', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                ->orWhere('person.login', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                ->orWhere('person.personID', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                ->orWhere('pe.emailADDR', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                ->orWhere('op.OrgStat1', 'LIKE', "%$query%");
        })->distinct()->get();
```

I've tested, using tinker, and can verify that the relations work as expected when grapping a Person record and using $p->roles.

The query above returns null when there should be data.  I'm concerned that it might be due to the select query but cannot find anything indicating if that's the issue nor how to remedy it.

**Edit**
Using dd(DB::getQueryLog()), I can see that the query generated for the with clause is asking for an extra field on the pivot table (which is needed) but is asking for it with a value of null.  How do I specify what it should be if it's not getting picked up from the relation definition in Person ?

The generated query:

```
        "query" => "select `roles`.*, `person_role`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `person_role`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id` from `roles` inner join `person_role` on `roles`.`id` = `person_role`.`role_id` where `person_role`.`org_id` is null and `person_role`.`user_id` in (1) ◀"
```

I can verify that the $this->defaultOrgID does have a non-null value which is referenced in the roles() relation function in Person.

Comment: Upon doing some additional debugging and looking at queries with dd(DB::getQueryLog()), I've uncovered the likely cause and am still looking for a solution.  I added this to the question above re: the additional field on the pivot table w/roles relation that is being requested as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56880217/laravel-relationship-additional-fields-in-pivot-table-linking-to-additional-mo) and I implemented the solution there - to create a custom pivot model in the way described and it seems to provide the expected data.

I'm still at a loss as to why I could get what I expected when using tinker but not within the application itself.